# Filtering a Vec of structs and creating new vector of Strings or strs in Rust

Tags: strings, rust, vectors

I'm working through the Rust book, and it has the following example of how to use the `filter` method on `Iterator`s ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html#using-closures-that-capture-their-environment)):

```
struct Shoe {
    size: u32,
    style: String,
}

fn shoes_in_my_size(shoes: Vec<Shoe>, shoe_size: u32) -> Vec<Shoe> {
    shoes.into_iter().filter(|s| s.size == shoe_size).collect()
}
```

I started thinking of how I could improve this function with the following objectives:

1. Do not consume/take ownership the `shoes` vector, so the caller can still use it.
2. Return a vector of just the `style`s, rather than of the whole `Shoe` struct.

I came up with the following two possible solutions:

```
fn shoe_styles_in_my_size(shoes: &[Shoe], shoe_size: u32) -> Vec<&String> {
    shoes
        .iter()
        .filter(|s| s.size == shoe_size)
        .map(|s| &s.style)
        .collect()
}
```

and:

```
fn shoe_styles_in_my_size(shoes: &[Shoe], shoe_size: u32) -> Vec<&str> {
    shoes
        .iter()
        .filter(|s| s.size == shoe_size)
        .map(|s| &s.style[..])
        .collect()
}
```

The difference being that the first example returns `Vec<&String>` and the second returns `Vec<&str>`.

What criteria would I use to determine which of these two is "better?"  I've been under the impression that using `str` is preferable to using `String` when possible, since it is more flexible (hopefully this is accurate?) Is there any overhead associated with the `[..]` operation?  My understanding says no, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[..]` slicing operation isn't going to cost anything, but isn't very descriptive either. I'd want to call `s.style.as_str()` instead.

As for the return type, I'd agree that `&str` is more appropriate, since it is the more general type. The functionality of a `String` is a superset of what you can do with a `str`, so it's irrelevant when that extra functionality isn't useful to the caller